# Creating html canvas automation tests with Test Studio

Tags: canvas, automated-tests, gojs, telerik-test-studio

I am currently investigating Telerik Test Studio to generate automated tests and I have been trying to figure out a way to create automated tests for our application that uses a GoJS html 5 canvas. I have noticed two ways so far:

1. Click on specific points (ActiveBrowser.Desktop.Mouse.Click(MouseClickType.LeftClick, 930, 405);). This seems to work provided that the browser always opens in full screen and that the elements in the canvas never change meaning that the tests might become obsolete so I don't believe it being the best approach.
2. There seems to be an HtmlCanvas class that I can't seem to find much information or examples on. I have tried to use it as follows but it does not seem as if I can access the elements or text in the canvas this way either:

   > HtmlCanvas canvas = new HtmlCanvas(ActiveBrowser.Find.AllElements().FirstOrDefault(w => w.TagName == "canvas"));

What would be the best way to approach this scenario? Where is a good place to find more information and examples regarding Test Studio HtmlCanvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you look at the http://gojs.net/latest/extensions/Robot.html sample, and then make use of the http://gojs.net/latest/extensions/Robot.js extension in your test system.

Note that the coordinates used by Robot are in GoJS document coordinates, not screen coordinates or any particular HTML element's coordinates.

Comment: Unfortunately at the rate our system's specs change, coordinates will never be an acceptable solution, thus the gojs robot tester will not work for us. The type of hooks I need from the canvas must be ids or something concrete at least, so in other words I need to hook onto the objects with something unique.

Comment: I can sympathize with that.  So you should not use any screen/page/mouse/touch/stylus coordinates at all.  So just call go.Diagram.fromDiv("myDiagramDiv") to get the http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Diagram.html that is being used in your app, and then use properties and call methods on the diagram and on its nodes and links to make sure everything is the way that you expect.  You won't depend on scroll position or scale or fonts or colors at all, unless you really want to.

Comment: @CSSmit - Did you able to automate it?